# Module not found error when importing umfpack MacOS Monterey M1 chip

Tags: python, scikits, umfpack

I installed **umfpack** using `pip install scikit-umfpack` and tried importing the umfpack module

> `from scikits import umfpack`

I'm running into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christianadib/pyfrbus_package/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scikits/umfpack/_umfpack.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('__umfpack', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '__umfpack'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/christianadib/pyfrbus_package/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scikits/umfpack/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .umfpack import *
  File "/Users/christianadib/pyfrbus_package/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scikits/umfpack/umfpack.py", line 130, in <module>
    from . import _umfpack as _um
  File "/Users/christianadib/pyfrbus_package/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scikits/umfpack/_umfpack.py", line 28, in <module>
    __umfpack = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/christianadib/pyfrbus_package/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scikits/umfpack/_umfpack.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import __umfpack
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__umfpack'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian, it's not easy:

1. [pypi umfpack](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-umfpack/) says: first build a local SuiteSparse UMFPACK
2. building [SuiteSparse](https://github.com/DrTimothyAldenDavis/SuiteSparse) libraries requires some knowledge of Makefiles 
   and on macos `otool / install_name_tool`
3. before `pip install`, you need a suitable [~/.numpy-site.cfg](https://scikit-umfpack.github.io/scikit-umfpack/install.html). 
   Added: the [setup.py](https://github.com/scikit-umfpack/scikit-umfpack/blob/master/setup.py) is old and messy;
   I had a simpler one which worked onceaponatime, let me know.

---

You could also try `conda install scikit-umfpack` instead of `pip`, 
BUT mixing different package managers is asking for trouble;
if you do, keep the pip and conda package trees separate.

Comment: @Christian: how did you solve this? I tried with a custom numpy-site, but I haven't got past the errors

Comment: I have tried following your instructions, and the installation seems successful (the installed umfpack libraries are found during the process). However, upon import, I get this error now: ImportError: cannot import name '_umfpack' from partially initialized module 'scikits.umfpack' (most likely due to a circular import). Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: @charles, if you're on MacOS maybe I could help (see `man dyld`), if not not, sorry, I have only a Mac. In any case can you put up exactly what you did, your `~/.numpy-site.cfg` and error message (as an answer, too long for a comment).